# Access overridden variables from parent function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution to my current workaround.

Javascript example:

```
var data= {
  'key1':'value1'
};

$.each(data,function foo() {
  alert(this); //alerts 'value1'
  $('#element').click(function()) {
    alert(this); //alerts something else
  }
});
```

The way to fix this would be:

```
var data= {
  'key1':'value1'
};


$.each(data,function foo() {
  alert(this); //alerts 'value1'

  var this_original=this;

  $('#element').click(function()) {
    alert(this_original); //alerts 'value1'
  }
});
```

This solves the problem, but it is not very clean. I was wondering if there was a nice Javascript/jQuery method to get the value of the original this inside of the child function. Something like: parentFunction.this

Comment: You're just going to have to get used to `var that = this;` within your code, I'm afraid. More detailed explanations are bound to follow, but it has to do with the fact that "this" is a reference to the object wherein the code is currently executing. Once you get inside the click function, you've shifted to a different context and "this" goes with it.

Comment: Would the jQuery "proxy" function help in any way?

Comment: Yes but I wouldn't recommend it unless you actually NEED that layer of complexity. The implication is that you would have to attach the event handler as a member of the object whose context you wanted to retrieve, i.e. declaring a member function called `onClick()` under `data`.

Comment: Ermm I'm sorry, but I don't really get that. Could you please give a code example for my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `this`, use the arguments instead:

```
var data= {
  'key1':'value1'
};

$.each(data,function foo(idx,val) {
  alert(val); //alerts 'value1'
  $('#element').click(function() {
    alert(val); //alerts 'value1'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the answer from Martin Jespersen.  However...

Using jQuery's [.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) function as requested:

```
var data = {
    "key1": "value1"
};

$.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    alert(this); //alerts 'value1'
    this.onClick = function() {
        alert(this);
    }

    $('#element').click($.proxy(this, "onClick"));
});
```

Here is [a fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/KAwAn/).

Please keep in mind you'd probably want to have a way to change the selector for where you're binding the click event, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could give you "assisted solution" points, but all I can do is +1

Comment: @Kranu Well, who knows? You may need it later for something unexpected. I'm here to share knowledge, not tally green checkmarks. :]

Answer (score -1):

Use [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/). You can use the following code:

```
 var data= {
  'key1':'value1'
};

$.each(data,function foo() {
  alert(this); //alerts 'value1'
  $('#element').click($.proxy(function() {
    alert(this); }, this);
});
```

Comment: That code will not function as intended. It will alert the HTMLElement.